# Scanning a txt of IP Addresses with and without subnets

Tags: python-3.x, ip-address

I have a large list of IP Addresses in a .txt file with and without a subnets. Lets call them the "BadList".

I have another set of IP Addresses in another .txt file (much smaller) and they do not have subnets. Lets call them the "TestList"

My goal is to scan the "Badlist" with the "Testlist" and print all matching IP's. If there is an IP with a subnet at the end, then print the IP address and the subnet that it was found in.

My trouble is with the subnet. I can loop through the list and find matching single IP addresses, but when it comes to the subnet, I cant get it to identify that X.X.X.X IP from TestList.txt was found in X.X.X.X/XX from Badlist.txt. It just skips over the IPs with the subnet.

I have tried tons of variations of code but here is one example.

```
import ipaddress

BadIPs = open("BadIPsWithandWithoutNets.txt", "r")
CheckIPs = open("IPsToCheck.txt", "r")

list1 = BadIPs.readlines()
list2 = CheckIPs.readlines()

for line1 in list1:
   for line2 in list2:
       line1 = line1.strip() 
       line2 = line2.strip():
       if line2 == ipaddress.ip_network(line1)     
           print('Matched IP {0} in IP Net {1}'.format(line2,line1))
```

Example of Bad IP list that i'm scanning. My real list is about 500mil: 
BadIPs = [192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.45, 192.168.0.0/24]

Thank you!

Comment: `ip1 = re.match('[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+', line1); ip2 = re.match('[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+', line1); if ip1 == ip2: ...`

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I used RE to separate the two different types of IP's before matching them to the  CheckIPs test file. It was the only way it would work for me. I changed it a bit. I first matched every single ip and then matched them to my test file. Then I matched every IP with a subnet, checked if my test file ips where in any of those subnets, then printed anything that matches.